# How To Get All User(s) Who Have AND Have't Give Their Comment

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel

I'm trying to generate a list of those who have commented and not per post like this:

| id | post_id | user_id | text | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | test | timestamp |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | test | timestamp |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | - | - |
| 4 | 1 | 4 | - | - |
| 5 | 1 | 5 | - | - |
| 6 | 1 | 6 | - | - |
| 7 | 2 | 1 | - | - |
| 8 | 2 | 2 | - | - |
| 9 | 2 | 3 | - | - |
| 10 | 2 | 4 | - | - |
| 11 | 2 | 5 | test | timestamp |
| 12 | 2 | 6 | - | - |

**Here are my tables:**

Posts Table:

| id | title | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Post 1 | timestamp |
| 2 | Post 2 | timestamp |

Comments Table :

| id | post_id | user_id | text | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | test | timestamp |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | test | timestamp |
| 3 | 2 | 5 | test | timestamp |

Users Table :

| id | name | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alfa | timestamp |
| 2 | Bravo | timestamp |
| 3 | Charlie | timestamp |
| 4 | Delta | timestamp |
| 5 | Echo | timestamp |
| 6 | Foxtrot | timestamp |

Is this possible? I already tried this code below, but when I filter it with `post_id`, it only shows users who have commented.

```
QueryBuilder::for(Comments::class)
->rightJoin(
  'users',
  'comments.user_id',
  'users.id',
)
->select(
  'comments.id',
  'users.id',
  'comments.post_id',
  'comments.text',
  'comments.updated_at'
)
->allowedFilters([
  'post_id',
])
```

Comment: `from users left join comments on ...` avoid that right join, make the main table users and then an outer join to comments

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL you can do this by trying code below:

```
SELECT case when comments.id is null then '-' else comments.id end,
       case when posts.id is null then '-' else posts.id end,
       case when users.id is null then '-' else users.id end,
       case when comments.text is null then '-' else comments.text end,
       case when comments.created_at is null then '-' else comments.created_at end
       FROM posts
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.post_id=posts.id
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id=comments.user_id
```

Comment: the `case when` statement will remplace null column by `-`

Answer (score 0):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and then `left join` to bring in existing data:

```
select p.id as post_id, u.id as user_id, c.text, c.created_at
from posts p cross join
     users u left join
     comments c
     on c.post_id = p.id and c.user_id = u.id
order by p.post_id, u.user_id;
```

This does not enumerate the rows.  If you want that, you can use `row_number()` for the first column:

```
select row_number() over (order by p.id, u.id) as id,
       p.id as post_id, u.id as user_id, c.text, c.created_at
from posts p cross join
     users u left join
     comments c
     on c.post_id = p.id and c.user_id = u.id
order by p.post_id, u.user_id;
```